# Why MySQL 8 doesn't return any rows when using a table with a descending PRIMARY KEY, 2 indexes, and valid join conditions with existing rows

Tags: mysql, index, primary-key, mysql-8.0, sorting

Using 2 tables (A & B), joinable by their PK, with the PRIMARY KEY of A being sorted DESC (PK in descending order as it's allowed by MySQL 8), and A having 2 indexes in ASC ordering.

When I perform a query like

```sql
SELECT * FROM `A` a
LEFT JOIN `B` b ON a.id <=> b.id
WHERE a.idx1 = 'X' AND a.idx2 = 'Y';
```

It will return nothing... BUT, if I add a precise condition like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `A` a
LEFT JOIN `B` b ON a.id <=> b.id
WHERE a.idx1 = 'X' AND a.idx2 = 'Y' AND a.id = 1337;
```

It will find the row with the specified value as PRIMARY KEY.

An explain show that MySQL will use 'index_merge_intersection' optimization when it doesn't find anything. If we disable the 'index_merge' optimizations, the first query will return all results as expected.

Why?

Answer (score 6):

It's actually a MySQL 8.0 bug (reported for MySQL 8.0.27-debug / 8.0.28), but also existing before (8.0.23) and seems to also exist on fork (MariaDB/Percona/AWS Aurora/...).

You can check if the bug get eventually fixed here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=106207

Before this, you can mitigate the problem by using one of these solutions:

### Do NOT use DESC ordering on your PRIMARY KEYS, only ASC

(This can also avoid the duplication of an INDEX appearing with a FOREIGN_KEY due to MySQL not being able to understand that the FK can use the DESC PK)

**OR**

### Disable the index_merge optimization from the optimizer_switch settings

By using the following query:

```sql
SET optimizer_switch='index_merge=off,index_merge_intersection=off';
```

(or by changing default/global value of optimizer_switch)
So MySQL will not be able to fall into this bug.

Comment: I guess the product is getting som complex that seemingly simple new features (DESC) can lead to edge cases that are not noticed for 'years'.

Answer (score 4):

"index_merge_intersection" almost always indicates the need for a more efficient "composite" index.  Add this index:

```
INDEX(idx1, idx2)
```

(and Drop `INDEX(idx1)`)

This should speed up the query; I don't know if it will work-around the bug mentioned by DarkCenobyte.

Comment: This would work-around the bug on my example case.
But as I recently migrated from 5.7 to 8. 0, I know that there is a risk in the project that the index_merge and the PKs passed in DESC occur on very dynamic queries with a lot of "where"-conditions possible and there is not necessarily a possibility of composite indexes for all possible queries (also because it would slow down the writing and the tables in question have heavy writing processes every day)
Index_merge_intersection could hint to improve indexes but it can be difficult to understand the bug in production when nothing is return.

Comment: @DarkCenobyte - I sympathize with your comments.  Index merge and DESC are obscure things; there are probably no test cases that mix them.  The DESC is probably never used by any query you have; it's use in the PK is especially rare.  Keep in mind that (except for index merge), only one index is used at a time.

Comment: @DarkCenobyte - It sounds like a better workaround is to get rid of DESC in the PK.  Please provide a case where that DESC is useful.  (I am having trouble envisioning a case where it is 'really' needed.)

Comment: @DarkCenobyte - Furthermore...  What was your PK?  If it has only one column, I can think of no case where `DESC` adds any _significant performance.  MySQL is quite happy to scan any index in reverse order.  The only use for `DESC` is when multiple columns are in the `ORDER BY` and there is a mixture of ASC and DESC.

Comment: You are right, I think the DESC on the PRIMARY KEY is not a good idea and I think I will remove this alteration on my PKs from my migration script 5.7 to 8.0.
I mainly wanted to benchmark if using a DESC PK could offer a performance gain on some tables, including a particular large table (800Gb of datas exported in CSV from this table) in my DB (that can't be partitioned because of relationships and a trigger on it)
I assumed that reading from the end to the beginning would make the index easier to navigate, but I read that the gain seems to profit only ORDER BY ... DESC queries.